# Using Rxjs, looking for a cleaner solution for combining array streams

Tags: javascript, rxjs

My issue is not with having working code, but my solution to combining streams of arrays seems fragile and I am sure Rxjs has a better solution.  The following is and example of what I have written:

```
var all$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    basicArray$, fastArray$, slowArray$,
    function(basic, fast, slow){
        return basic.concat(fast).concat(slow);
});
```

My goal is three in -> one out and only when there all three are new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a utility (like lodash's `flatten` method), you can accomplish the same using the following:

```
var all$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(basicArray$, fastArray$, slowArray$)
    .map(_.flatten);
```

Looking at your last comment, however, I don't think your code works as expected. The stream resulting from `combineLatest` will emit a new item as soon as any of the streams emits.

Based on your description, the `zip` operator might be more appropriate: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md

Comment: .zip makes sense in making a better solution.  Thank you for that feedback